# Gradle Build fails for Spring Boot

Tags: spring, gradle

I have below gradle configuration file. and get error in building project with command- `gradle clean install`. I want to know if my version of spring gradle plugin is old or there any configuration is missing in Gradle build script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
war {
    baseName = 'webapp'
    version =  ''
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {

compile("org.springframework:spring-test:4.2.4.RELEASE")

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.3.1.RELEASE")
compile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.1.0")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
compile("org.json:json:20090211")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile( "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.28" )
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.0.2")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.0.2")
compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2")
 compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2')
 compile('net.sourceforge.argo:argo:3.19')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")


compile ("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2")
compile ("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4")

}
```

Error-

```
board>gradle clean install

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Dashboard'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.1.
RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3
.1.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springfram
ework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.3
.1.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Host name may not contain blanks

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Comment: I see resource hosted on maven, but not able to download same using gradle.

Comment: is building with gradle command deprecated and I need to use gradlew for grade version- 4.0.2

Comment: what does `nslookup repo1.maven.org` return on your system? It looks like something is messing with your name resolution.

Comment: Yes, I see nslookup working. I found entries in gradle.properties for proxy server and port incorrect. I corrected it and it worked like charm!